# How to convert generated Private Key in Openssh format to integrate subversion in IDEA IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, cygwin, key, putty, openssh

I needed to generate a private/public key that is in openssh format to have me integrate subversion repository to IntelliJ. I have used `puttyKeygen.exe` already to generate a initial key. But while integrating in IntelliJ, its failing me to authenticate with a same Private key.
How can I convert the Putty generated private/public initial key to an openssh format. As I read, that the Subversion integration in IntelliJ uses the Cygwin/openssh format of the private key.

P.S: I have tried puTTykeygen to do the same but no luck! IDEA IDE still fails to authenticate.

Anyone who can shed some light on it would be really helpful.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
After going through the following steps to create an Openssh private key :
`puttygen has a menu: Conversion -> Export OpenSSH Key That will save the private key to the openssh format`.

I have again tried integrating the IDEA using the same key that got generated using above mentioned direction. and got myself failed with the same message saying authentication failed!

[image]

I am assuming, the key I obtained is either not openssh format or is there anything I am proceeding wrong with a integration. Could anyone please let me know what possibly could be the reason of me not able to integrate subversion in IDEA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Make sure the initial keys that are put to use are one time generated not repeatedly.
```

Go to Puttykeygen-> conversions-> import the private key(.ppk file) you have generated initially and then-> export openssh key-> save it to the same location and then go to IDEA and follow the below steps:
1.  Go to Version control-> Checkout from Version Control-> Subversion and provide the same key and your passphrase.
2. click checkout by providing your username.

It should work!

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was using different generated keys in order to checkout!